# Unexpected behaviour in C++ function overloading

Tags: c++, overloading

Consider the following code.

```
class MyClass1
{
public:
  MyClass1(const int& i)
  {
    myVar = i;
  }

  const int& get() const
  {
    std::cout<<"Inside 1 \n";
    return myVar;
  }

  int get()
  {
    std::cout<<"Inside 2 \n";
    return myVar;
  }

private:
    int myVar;
};

class MyClass2
{
public:
  MyClass2(const int& i)
  {
    myVar = i;
  }

  const int& get()
  {
    std::cout<<"Inside 3 \n";
    return myVar;
  }

  int get() const
  {
    std::cout<<"Inside 4 \n";
    return myVar;
  }

private:
    int myVar;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  MyClass1 myClass1(10);
  int tmp1 = myClass1.get();
  const int& tmp2 = myClass1.get();


  MyClass2 myClass2(10);
  int tmp3 = myClass2.get();
  const int& tmp4 = myClass2.get();

  return 0;
}
```

The output showed the following.

```
Inside 2 
Inside 2 
Inside 3 
Inside 3
```

For "const int& tmp2 = myClass1.get();" I expected that it will print call "const int& get() const" in MyClass1. To my surprise, it called "int get()" in both the cases in MyClass1.
In MyClass2, I swapped the "const" and then I found that in the function calls it called "const int& get()".
Why is it happening like this?

Comment: The only way in C++ to overload based on return type is to overload cast operator...

Comment: @W.F. - it's a **conversion** operator, not a **cast** operator. There are conversions that can be done without a cast.

Comment: @PeteBecker you're right the wording wasn't ever my good side...

Comment: [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ti1myXGA40cAidAV)

Comment: @W.F. Thanks for your response. But my intention is to get the output through some member function and the returned variable type may be used defined!

Comment: @Soo I see, then the only way I can think of is tag dispatching, but it would require additional dummy parameter to your getter to pass there a type of result...

Answer (score 5):

> For "const int& tmp2 = myClass1.get();" I expected that it will print call "const int& get() const" in MyClass1.

You don't explain why you expect this, but you certainly shouldn't. There are two `get` functions that take no parameters, one `const` and the other not. Since `myClass1` is not `const`, the function that is not `const` is called.

Were it not this way, there would be no point in allowing two class member functions that have the same name and take the same parameters to differ only in that one is `const` and the other isn't.